# Could not find installable ISAM In Network Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection

I am trying to connect Access database which is located on Main server.

Here is the code:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AccessConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\Gimelsms\TCMS V3\ingress.mdb; Persist Security Info=False; Jet OLEDB: Database Password=ingress;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But I am getting "Could not find installable ISAM" Error.

Can anyone please help me.

Regards

Comment: ACE comes with Microsoft Office and is in the Program Files (x86) Folder and is named ACEOLEDB.DLL. You have to use the version (like 12.0) that is installed with office. If you do not have office installed you need to go to msdn and install the runtime version of ACE.  It is in a folder like : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15 (version 15)

Comment: Office is installed in my system. But still I am getting this error.

Comment: What version of shared\OFFICEXX?  The one that contains the ACEOLEDB.DLL (you could have more than one shared folder).  Change the  connection string number 12.0 to match the folder.

Comment: Office version is 2016. And I am not sharing office. I am sharing mdb file only.

Comment: Office 2016 is version 16 (not all years and version match).  So what folder is the ACEOLEDB.DLL located?  If is is in the shared\OFFICE16 then change the connection string from 12.0 to 16.0.

Comment: Tried already but no luck.

Comment: Usually it would mean that there was no Office License.  Can you open the access database with access?  Sometimes after new version of office is installed you have to open file so it gets updated to match version of office.

Comment: My version is latest version and I opened database just before posting my question here.

Comment: It is not finding the file  ACEOLEDB.DLL. in the shared\OFFICE16 folder.

Comment: It is there in shared\OFFICE16 folder. I have checked.

Comment: It been a long time since I've gotten same error.I was trying to modify a real old version of an access database (before 2003) and to modify in c# I had to convert to access 2003, make changes, and then save back as pre 2003.I don't think your issue is with the version of the database.The database has an internal property which indicates the version when the database was created.Even though you upgraded to 2016 the internal property may still be older.  Right now I could try removing "Jet OLEDB:Database" which may not be needed.  See https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ for other options.

Comment: It has been solved. My access database file format was .mdb. I save it in new version format to .accdb and it worked. Thanks for help.

Comment: If it was mdb then you should of used jet instead of ace.  Thanks for reminding me of the fix.

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved. My access database file format was .mdb. I save it in new version format to .accdb and it worked.